# Add nodes in grid style

Tags: 6

I need to add nodes in grid style i.e inline adding of the nodes should be done there only. i.e use can add any number of nodes at a time.

Comment: Huh? I have no idea what that question means. Do you mean you want to list nodes in a grid type fashion? what parts of the node? Title? body? how many columns? how many rows?

Comment: @blue928 - I am talking about add content form. The form is in a vertical manner. Client want to add 10 nodes in 1 shot and its should be in a grid manner i.e. the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) plus [Slickgrid](http://drupal.org/project/slickgrid) to do that.

[image: Screenshot]

The module:

> defines a slickgrid view style, so all data can be output as an editable grid.

And can also be used for data entry/manipulation directly within the grid itself.

Comment: so then, you think the question has to do with the ability to modify multiple nodes at once?

Comment: "I need to add nodes in grid style" doesn't leave a lot of room for ambiguity really

Comment: @blue928 - Can i add new entry from here..

Comment: @Hacker Yes, you can use Flexigrid to add new entries. Have a look at the module page for the full ist of features

Comment: @Clive - Let me be clear, i want to add nodes using grids.

Comment: Yes, Flexi _grid_ will let you add nodes in a _grid_. Have you tried it? If this isn't what you want I'm afraid I don't understand the question :/

Comment: @Clive - i did not find the module only on drupal. Can you please share the link

Comment: Do you mean the SlickGrid library? You can get it from: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid

Answer (score 0):

[Editview](http://drupal.org/project/editview) module also proved useful for me.